# How do I acces iframe with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, input

I have Google in an iframe. I want to have some control over the input so I tried:

```
  $('#iframeID').contents().find('input').keydown(function () {

     $(".SomeDiv").hide();

 });
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you can't do this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer the question without the underlying code, but have a look at [this forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-how-to-access-iframe-window). At the bottom is a jQuery example, in which the same problem as you have is solved with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the iframe content which is in a different domain than its parent unless you map the domain which mostly is not allowed in all the browsers due to security reasons.

The below link might help you

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes